# How to interpet Visual Studio 2019 performance profile of UWP Store App

Tags: performance, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, performance-testing, visual-studio-debugging

We have a UWP app that has been in the Microsoft Store for 7+ years. Our latest version is much slower than previous versions from the store, although in debug performance is fine. For example, navigating to a page now takes 10-30 secs. In debug it takes 1-2 seconds. In previous versions from the store it took 1-2 seconds.

I ran the store app. In Visual Studio 2019 I attached the performance profiler to the running app and navigated to the job page.

In 10 seconds 9940 events were captured. CPU usage shows 77% kernel, 11% UI, 11% Graphics

The events are mainly Windows Kernel and other Windows dlls. If I click Just My Code, I see the same list of events.
The Hot Path is

```
ntdll.dll 89% cpu
kernel32.dll 89% cpu
SHCore.dll 79% cpu
ApplicationFrame.dll 33% cpu
```

I can drill down but all I see is more Windows dlls. How do I use this information to find out why the current version of this app is so much slower than the previous version in navigating to this page.

**EDIT** I also ran the preformance profiler on a previous version from the store.  A Similar number of events are gathered but the Hot Path is:

```
[External Code] 100% cpu
```

What could we have done to change the Hot Path for the same bit of navigation? Is this something about the way it is being built for release by the store?

Comment: I know that the biggest difference between `Debug` and `Release` should be the `.net native tool chain` [feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/dotnet-native/). When build under Release, it will be enabled. This is designed for better compiling and deploying, I’m not sure if this will affect the performance of the application. Does disable it work(Property > Build > Compile with .NET Native tool chain)?

Comment: Our app has been using the .Net Native Tool chain for years. You cannot submit to the Microsoft Store without it. So that can't be the difference.

Comment: Ok, looks like, it may be related to the Windows OS/System files. Have you tried to run it on another machine? Does the application work well locally, I mean not from store, and not run(debugging) in VS?

Comment: We have many customers around the world who have been using our app for years. Many complain the latest version is slow. It is fast in debug on any machine (that has vs). The store version is slow on any machine, including dev machines. If the performance profiler won't read the symbols file for user code, it's not much help.

Comment: I think the performance profiler won’t read the symbols file, as you know, [normally it is tested under Release Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2019#collect-cpu-usage-data). I’m unable to know whether the issue happens during the process of packing to store, or it happens right after building under Release mode. This issue is hard to check, maybe need to check the codes, notice the memory...

Comment: I believe that the build process under Release mode should do harmless things for your application, but if it is caused by the build process(improvement process), it will be hard to find.

Comment: To run a UWP app in Release mode you have to uncheck .Net Native Tool chain. Then performance in release mode is fine. So running locally in Release mode doesn't tell us much about how it will run once the store releases it.